# ArcGIS Pro SDK: Programmatically toggle whether a layer is editable or not

Tags: arcgis

I was wondering if anyone would know how to toggle whether a layer is editable or not.

I am building a custom Add-in and would like a way to make a layer editable or uneditable based on layer name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out it was quite simple in the end had to use 'SetEditable' method from layer.

```
fl.SetEditable(true);
```